# How do I get the final rendered HTML of a remote URL?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm trying to get the visible HTML of a remote page into a string, after the scripts (aspx, javascript) have executed.

To be exact, I want the same HTML as if I went to chrome and pressed F12. The visible HTML, the final rendered HTML.

I've been struggling with this for days, so it would be lovely to get some instructions here.
If you have any questions, or feel like my question isn't clean, ask away.

Answer (score 0):

You need a WebView that Renders the page and executes JavaScript.
Or try an engline like phantomjs. That does the JavaScript rendering for you.

Afterwards you can get the full dom of the html page.